# How open million of records in Excel? Can other software for this

Tags: excel, apache-spark

I have Excel file which has about a million records in one Sheet. When I open in Excel it can't load properly. How do I open this record? Can other software to open this data properly?

Comment: What is a lack record?

Comment: A lakh is 100 000 in the Indian numberInga system. He means he’s got over one million records.

Comment: If you are storing this many records, why are you not using a database?

Comment: all the record or in excel file. i don't have database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has a limit of round about 1 million rows.You Cannot load more than a million rows in Excel.

Comment: Can other software to open this file

Comment: @MuhammadTayyeb, Try this http://www.delimitware.com/, which is capable of open up to 2 billion rows and 2 million columns very quickly has a free 15 day trial too.

Answer (score 1):

10 Lakh records means 1 million records, to open such a file you need a really good processor and good RAM, I use a Octa Core machine with 32GB RAM which has no issues opening such large files

Comment: I am not asking about system. I am asking about Excel can't open large file.ron editor is a software that open like this file

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to perform this kind of analysis in Excel, then you can use Power Query (Free add-in for Excel 2010 & 2013, but included in Excel 2016 as Get & Transform).

Power Query is a Microsoft Development and is part of Excel from 2016 onwards..

With Power Query, it loads millions of rows into an internal database engine. and you perform analysis generally by pivotting. You will not be able to see the data in a worksheet because the limit of 1048K still exists, but any aggregation analysis is possible.